# I have a nested list, but i want to add a nested list inside the nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like:

```
[[21, 32, 32], [23, 34, 32], [32, 34, 57]]
```

I would like to convert each number to its own list like

```
[[[21], [32], [32]], [[23], [34], [32]], [[32], [34], [57]]]
```

How would i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `[[[x] for x in sub_lst] for sub_lst in lst]`

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service. Post an example of the code you have tried that is not working first.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> lst = [[21, 32, 32], [23, 34, 32], [32, 34, 57]]
>>> new_lst = [[[i] for i in sub_lst] for sub_lst in lst]
>>> new_lst
[[[21], [32], [32]], [[23], [34], [32]], [[32], [34], [57]]]
```

---

You can also use `numpy` by simply adding an extra axis using [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) while *slicing* your array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([[21, 32, 32], [23, 34, 32], [32, 34, 57]])
>>> l[:, :, np.newaxis] # or l[:, :, None]
array([[[21],
        [32],
        [32]],

       [[23],
        [34],
        [32]],

       [[32],
        [34],
        [57]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `numpy.reshape()`:

```
import numpy as np 
arr = np.array([[21, 32, 32], [23, 34, 32], [32, 34, 57]])

arr.reshape(3,3,1)

# array([[[21],
#         [32],
#         [32]],

#        [[23],
#         [34],
#         [32]],

#        [[32],
#         [34],
#         [57]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Method using list comprehension:

```
a = [[21, 32, 32], [23, 34, 32], [32, 34, 57]]

print [[[element] for element in each] for each in a]
```

Output:

```
[[[21], [32], [32]], [[23], [34], [32]], [[32], [34], [57]]]
```